# Type alias from main sources not available in test

Tags: scala, sbt

When compiling my test sources, I get the following error:

```
.../test/com/pckg/Spec.scala:2:18: Symbol 'type com.pckg.X' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value com.pckg.XUser.x'
Make sure that type X is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'XUser.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.pckg.package.
```

A full rebuild (`clean`) does not help the problem

The alias and class are defined as follows:

```
package com

package object pckg {
  type X = Int
}
```

XUser.scala:

```
package com.pckg

case class XUser(x: X)
```

Spec.scala:

```
package com.pckg

class Spec {
   val xuser = XUser(1)
}
```

What could cause this? Scala 2.12.8 and sbt 1.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `test/com/pckg/package.scala` also existed, and defined a different package object (with utilities for the test code). Apparently this overwrites the main source package object.

Comment: Yes, this isn't specific to package objects, the same should happen when you have classes/traits with the same name in `main` and in `test`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It's clear once you know what is happening, but in practice a package object is more a container for top-level things that cannot be top-level (functions, type aliases, values). That was my intention, so it's really counter-intuitive when declaring an additional top-level thing in `test` that all top-level things from `main` disappear. I wasn't thinking in terms of "I am going to create an object named `pckg` with these members".